# Android on Chrome problems: MutliWindowMode + Overlay problems causing SharedElements to offset

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

As you can see in the video below, the start and end of the transition between shared elements is bizarrely offset when the Activity is on the right side when split screened.

[image: gif]

<sup>View high res video [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/wcubvs46kjcT7My53)</sup>

Transitions work just fine if full screen or the Activity is anchored to the left.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Transition is occurring between Fragment A and Activity B.
The clickListener for the Fragment RecyclerAdapter is below.

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(final ChartViewHolder viewHolder, int position, final Chart chart) {
    viewHolder.setChart(chart);
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clickListener.onChartClicked(chart, viewHolder);
        }
    });
}
```

fyi. I've also tried passing the position along to onChartClicked and obtaining the sharedelement directly from the recycleradapter in Fragment A but that didn't work either.

Fragment A.onchartClicked is below.

```
@Override
public void onChartClicked(Chart chart, MyChartRecyclerAdapter.ChartViewHolder viewHolder) {


    mClickedChart = viewHolder;

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChartDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PhysioHelper.ARG_DB_REF, "orgs/" + mOrgKey + "/clients/" + mClientKey + "/charts/" + chart.getUid());
    intent.putExtra(PhysioHelper.ARG_CLIENT_NAME, mClientName);
    intent.putExtra(PhysioHelper.ARG_CLIENT_KEY, mClientKey);

    View decor = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
    View statusBar = decor.findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground);
    View navBar = decor.findViewById(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground);

    List<Pair<View, String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    pairs.add(Pair.create((View) viewHolder.chartlistcard, viewHolder.chartlistcard.getTransitionName()));

    pairs.add(Pair.create((View) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar), getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar).getTransitionName()));

    if (statusBar != null)
        pairs.add(Pair.create(statusBar, Window.STATUS_BAR_BACKGROUND_TRANSITION_NAME));
    if (navBar != null)
        pairs.add(Pair.create(navBar, Window.NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND_TRANSITION_NAME));


    Bundle options = makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),
            pairs.toArray(new Pair[pairs.size()])).toBundle();
    startActivity(intent, options);

}
```

It appears as though makeSceneTransitionAnimation is mistakenly offsetting all shared elements (toolbar included) by precisely double the width of the Activity on the left.
fwiw. The same problem exists when running on Chromebook when App is resized and the App is not anchored in the top left (0,0).
When anchored in top left everything is great.
When not anchored in top left, x and y coordinates of the shared elements appear to be offset by twice the distance of the activity's distance from 0,0.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.
Thanks

**Update**: setSharedElementsUseOverlay(false) 'fixes' the offset problem but introduces other transition problems so it's definitely not a solution.

I'm not very familiar with Overlays.  Why is the Overlay in the wrong position when the Activity is MultiWindowMode on the right side of the screen?
(Reminder, there are no problems with Activity is on the left side)

Since I've struggled far too long with this, I've decided to avoid transitions when activity is not full screen.

Things I've tried include:
-Removing constraint layouts
-ActivityOptions.setLaunchBounds
-Setting all layouts to fitsSystemWindow=true
-Wrapping shared elements in Framelayouts

**Update #2**
From what I have learned so far, Android apps on Chrome require             ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), null);   (or replace null with shared element pairs) for ANY cross activity transitions to work.

And by cross activity transitions, I mean any window enter/exit/reenter/return transions set in the Activities theme (v21\styles).

But there are more problems.
If Activity A is active (Main activity containing parent/detail fragments) and a window resize occurs such that Activity A launches Activity B (containing details fragment), then Activity A remains visibly on top of Activity B ... but touches are received by Activity B!!
Basically the enter transition for Activity B doesn't occur!!

To resolve this problem, I'm forced to detect a resize in activity A, pass that knowledge to Activity B, then force Activity B to not use any enter transition.

```
    if (useEnterTransition == false)
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(null);
```

fyi, default enter transition on Activity B is @android:transition/slide_right (set in Theme)

All of this is just very strange.

If anyone comes up with an answer for the bizarre Overlay offset, I look forward to hearing about it.

Comment: Can you verify, that transitions work as expected when **not** in multi-window mode?

Comment: Correct. They work fine when full screen and in multi-mode when anchored to the top left corner of the screen.  fwiw, I should mention that running on Chrome, isInMultiMode returns true all the time, so it would seem that isn't one of the factors.  The app simply must be anchored in top/left in order for Overlay / transitions to work correctly.